# Sending Json Arrays within Object to API

Tags: c#, json, post, asp.net-web-api, json.net

i need to POST arrays within object to api that will looks like this:

```
{
  "ds_seatInfo": [
    {
      "SEAT_LOC_NO": "00201901",
      "SEAT_LOC_NO": "00201902"
    }
  ],
  "SCN_SCH_SEQ": "13178",
  "REQ_FG_CD": "01",
  "LOCK_APRV_KEY": "123123"
}
```

i was tried using Models that define as follow:

```
 public class ds_seatInfo
    {
        public List<string> SEAT_LOC_NO { get; set; }
    }

 public class BookParam
    {
        public string SCN_SCH_SEQ { get; set; }
        public ds_seatInfo ds_seatInfo { get; set; }
        public string REQ_FG_CD { get; set; }
        public string LOCK_APRV_KEY { get; set; }
    }
```

but the result aren't as expected, that's model return:

```
"{\"SCN_SCH_SEQ\":\"13178\",\"ds_seatInfo\":{\"SEAT_LOC_NO\":[\"00201901\",\"00201902\"]},\"REQ_FG_CD\":\"01\",\"LOCK_APRV_KEY\":\"123123\"}"
```

which means the SEAT_LOC_NO doesn't read as expected. i am using Newtonsoft for Serialize the Model.

What should i do?

Comment: What's the method signature on the WebApi action?

Comment: @DiskJunky HTTPPost

Comment: I mean how is the method declared, e.g., `public void DoSomething(SomeObject param1, ...)`

Comment: i don't know since i got the API from another vendor. and they doesn't provides documentation. Just a way to execute its parameters.

Comment: Then create a test web api project that accepts the JSON and attempt to parse it in your own code. This will help you track down what part you don't have right

Comment: Just to confirm -- does your JSON really have two duplicated, identical properties `"SEAT_LOC_NO"` **in the same object**?  According to the [most recent JSON rfc](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7159#section-4), *An object whose names are all unique is interoperable in the sense that all software implementations receiving that object will agree on the name-value mappings.  When the names within an object are not  unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is  unpredictable.*

Comment: I think no, it's looks like an array and only send its value. Maybe since i'm using List<string> ? But thank you for your information.

Comment: *I think no, it's looks like an array and only send its value.* - in that case can you [edit] your question to show the JSON you really need to post?  It's much more difficult to generate JSON with duplicate property names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't tested it, but may be this will help you or get you in the right direction:

```
public class BookParam
{
    [JsonProperty("ds_seatInfo")]
    public List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> SetInfos = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

    [JsonProperty("SCN_SCH_SEQ")]
    public string ScnSchSeq { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("REQ_FG_CD")]
    public string ReqFgCd { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LOCK_APRV_KEY")]
    public string LockAprvKey { get; set; }
}
```

And when you add items to SetInfos try like this:

```
SetInfos.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("SEAT_LOC_NO", "00201901"));
```

**Edit**

Another possible implementation

```
public class BookParam
{
    [JsonProperty("ds_seatInfo")]
    public List<SeatInfo> DsSeatInfo = new List<SeatInfo>();

    [JsonProperty("SCN_SCH_SEQ")]
    public string ScnSchSeq { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("REQ_FG_CD")]
    public string ReqFgCd { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("LOCK_APRV_KEY")]
    public string LockAprvKey { get; set; }
}

public class SeatInfo()
{
     [JsonProperty("SEAT_LOC_NO")]
     public string SeatLocNo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you mate, this one solved my problem. Though it's also send 'Key' and 'Value' inside object.

Comment: No problem, I added an edit with another way that may also work for you and will not have the key and value issue.